# Infinite address nesting

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to move through `.htaccess` from such addresses:

`/one/two/thre/four/five/.../.../.../`

There can be any characters and nesting after `/`.

And it turns out this crap flies out:

> **Not Found**
> The requested URL `/sdfsdf/sdfsdf/sdfsdf/sdf/` was not foundon this server.

And you need to transfer to the main page, if not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved!
Who needs it, I leave it here:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    ErrorDocument 404 https://%{HTTP_HOST}
</If>
<Else>
    ErrorDocument 404 http://%{HTTP_HOST}
</Else>
```